# how to generate data-target for bootstrap accordion with php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make each WordPress post to produce a bootstrap accordion in a grid (which I am using bootstrap grid classes). But I am having trouble generating these random data-target attributes for each specific post.

These are just the static parts that I have tried before importing them into wordpress and connecting my actual content to the accordion.

```
<?php $uuid = uniqid(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<img src="img/x.jpg" id="toggle-btn"
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $uuid;?>">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<img src="img/y.jpg" id="toggle-btn"
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $uuid;?>">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
<img src="img/z.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>

</div>

<div id="<?php echo $uuid;?>" class="collapse">
<img src="img/x-collapsed.jpg">
</div>
<div id="<?php echo $uuid;?>" class="collapse">
<img src="img/y-collapsed.jpg">
</div>
<div id="<?php echo $uuid;?>" class="collapse">
<img src="img/z-collapsed.jpg">
</div>
```

The first one works as expected but even before trying I can tell the second one and third and so on doesn't. Remember these wants to be generated through wordpress posts and each needs to have its own unique data-target to show the related info box when clicked open. 
Thus this actual code is going to be inside a foreach like the following: (i don't need help with this one though)

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
...

}
```

Right now it gives me the same collapsed-box as the first one, which make sense since I didn't do anything to $uuid to increment it to correspond to its parent.

All I need help with is only the data-target, how can I make it so for each accordion there is a unique data-target generated that correspond to its actual collapsed box. I am guessing I should concatinate a var to this: 
    
but I have no clue how to.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an working example of accordion made from Bootstrap. IDs are generated dynamically to avoid conflict. Please check following example and you can customize it as per your requirement. First card is open by default and other are collapsed in initial.

```
<?php
$qargs = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'no_found_rows'       => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $qargs );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="accordion">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            $heading_id = 'heading-' . get_the_ID();
            $content_id = 'collapse-' . get_the_ID();
            $is_first = ( 0 === $the_query->current_post ) ? true : false;
            ?>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $heading_id ); ?>">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo esc_attr( $content_id ); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php echo esc_attr( $content_id ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div id="<?php echo esc_attr( $content_id ); ?>" class="collapse <?php echo ( $is_first ) ? 'show': ''; ?>" aria-labelledby="<?php echo esc_attr( $heading_id ); ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .card -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div><!-- #accordion -->
<?php endif; ?>
```